# preventDefault not working in form submit in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, forms, safari, preventdefault

I am trying to get Safari to validate my form and stop it from submitting if required fields are not filled in. I currently have the following submit function.

```
$('#qtrAuditform').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  if (/safari/.test(uagent) && !/chrome/.test(uagent)) {
    //If required attribute is not supported or browser is Safari (Safari thinks that it has this attribute, but it does not work), then check all fields that has required attribute
    $("#qtrAuditform [required]").each(function(index) {
      if (!$(this).val()) {
        //If at least one required value is empty, then ask to fill all required fields.
        alert("Please fill all required fields.");
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
  var $form = $(this),
    data = $form.serialize();
  var url = 'http://localhost:8888/datatest';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function() {
      alert('Your form has been successfully submitted!');
    },
    fail: function() {
      alert('something went wrong...try again');
    }
  });
});
```

I get the alert to please fill in the required fields, but then immediately after I also get the alert that the form has submitted. How can I make it to not submit the form while still making the fields that are required to be filled in?

Comment: The `return false;` has to apply to the event listener function, not the function in `each`. Also, you have `event.preventDefault` twice.

Comment: So I commented out the first preventdefault, and moved the return false; to the on submit function but I still get the same result. Suggestions?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is what I now have, that works.

```js
$('#qtrAuditform').on('submit',function(event){
    //event.preventDefault();
    var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
   if(/safari/.test(uagent) && !/chrome/.test(uagent)) {
   //If required attribute is not supported or browser is Safari (Safari thinks that it has this attribute, but it does not work), then check all fields that has required attribute
   $("#qtrAuditform [required]").each(function(index) {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
     //If at least one required value is empty, then ask to fill all required fields.
     alert("Please fill all required fields.");
     //event.preventDefault();
     return false;
    }
   });
   return false;
  }
    var $form = $(this),
    data = $form.serialize();
    var url = 'http://localhost:8888/datatest';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(){
            //window.location = "http://www.google.com";
   alert('Your form has been successfully submitted!');
    
        },
        fail:function(){
            alert('something went wrong...try again');
        }
    });
 return false;
});
```

The only thing it does not do correctly is return the alert that the form has been submitted correctly in Safari. It does return that alert in other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The whole event should immediately return false.

```
    $('#qtrAuditform').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  if (/safari/.test(uagent) && !/chrome/.test(uagent)) {
    //If required attribute is not supported or browser is Safari (Safari thinks that it has this attribute, but it does not work), then check all fields that has required attribute
    $("#qtrAuditform [required]").each(function(index) {
      if (!$(this).val()) {
        //If at least one required value is empty, then ask to fill all required fields.
        alert("Please fill all required fields.");
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
  var $form = $(this),
    data = $form.serialize();
  var url = 'http://localhost:8888/datatest';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function() {
      alert('Your form has been successfully submitted!');
    },
    fail: function() {
      alert('something went wrong...try again');
    }
  }); 
 //Return false immediately
 return false;
});
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: I tried this and am still getting the same result as I was getting before.